# How to click on the element as per the HTML provided through selenium-webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Hello I tried to click on a radio button with the help of selenium driver in python and it does not works . This is HTML CODE :

```
<input aria-flowto="aria8" aria-label="private key" type="radio" ng-model="walletType" value="pasteprivkey" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" name="200">
```

This is my line of code :

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("input[type='radio'][value='pasteprivkey']").click()
```

And I get this error :

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52666/devtools/browser/da96711c-0446-c01-a90d-0f722691ec4c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\py\teste.py", line 6, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio'][@value='pasteprivkey']").click()
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Someone can help me please ? I also tried to copy xpath with inspect element and I get this weird thing :

```
/html/body/section[1]/div[1]/main/article[1]/div[2]/wallet-decrypt-drtv/article/section[1]/label[9]/input
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QXZjPkNf

Answer (score 1):

The error message is indicating that the element is not visible.

Your selector **IS** finding the input element, but when attempting the click, Selenium is reporting it is not visible. Selenium does not allow click events on elements that are either entirely hidden or are behind other elements.

Without access to your web page, it is impossible to understand why this element is not visible. You could try one of the following;

- Understand the steps that will display the element, and perform those within your script
- Find a different element that should be interacted with instead
- Use Javascript to execute the click (NB. I do not recommend this if you are using Selenium for testing)

Finally;

> I also tried to copy xpath with inspect element and I get this weird thing

That is an XPath and the one suggested by your browser.  It should be remembered that XPath is not a definitive thing; an element can be found by many, many XPaths.  Some of these XPaths will be good, some will be bad.  Selecting the most suitable XPath is something that takes experience and knowledge of automation, and as you have seen, this is very hard to achieve via tooling.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to invoke `click()` on it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-touched[ng-model='walletType'][value='pasteprivkey']"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched' and @ng-model='walletType'][@value='pasteprivkey']"))).click()
  ```
- Note : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Name driver is not defined for both lines of code that you wrote ( for xpath and css ). I also tried to replace that driver with my variable browser=webdriver.Chrome() but it doesn't woks

Comment: @Theminer Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status